# Creating a Matrix on a Subclass

Tags: java, matrix, subclass

I've created a class Mappa with a method to create a numerical matrix Matrice, then i've created a subclass MappaFermi and there i've written an specific content of the matrix but there's an error saying that array constants can only be used as initializers, any suggestions?

```
public class Mappa {
    private final Settore [][] settore;
    private int Matrice [][];
    private static final int X=23;
    private static final int Y=14;
    public Mappa (){
        settore = new Settore[X][Y];
        for (int i=0; i < X; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<Y; j++) {
                settore[i][j] = new Settore (i,j);
            }
        }
        Matrice = new int[23][14];
    }

    public int[][] getMatrice() {
        return Matrice;
    }

    public void setMatrice(int matrice[][]) {
        Matrice = matrice;
    }
}

public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {
    public MappaFermi() {

        Matrice={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
    }
}
```

Comment: the `{ .. }` initialization for the Matrice array can only be used when declaring the variable

Answer (score 2):

- We don't have the classes `Settore`.
- `Matrice` is private hence can't be accessed in `MappaFermi`, you need to use `setMatrice` method.
- You forgot the instantiation `new int[][]`

```
setMatrice(new int[][]
{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0 ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
});
```

Comment: thanks, i thought that all attributes of a superclass could be accessed by a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid syntax. Inline array initialization has the following form:

```
Matrice = new int[][] {{//your definition

}}
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard True, but there are other issues in the code even besides this, I'm answering the question specifically asked about this error.

Comment: you can use the constant syntax when you declare the variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize it like that, you need to initialize it outside of a method.

```
public class MappaFermi extends Mappa {
    Matrice={{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,2,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,1,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,1,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}};
}

    public MappaFermi() {

    }
}
```

Comment: True, but the syntax is, itself, valid. Other posters are giving slightly incorrect information, and I wanted to supplement.

Comment: Kon's answer, for instance. "You are using invalid syntax." The syntax is valid, its just in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using array initializer `={{}}` you cannot split declaration `private int Matrice [][];` in base class and assignment `Matrice = {{}}` in sub class or any other way.
Both declaration and assignment should be in same statement if you want to use form `={{}};`

Please set values on `Matrice` by iterating over each element like
  `Matrice[i][j] = <value>;`
if you are using it in base class.